# React auth route redirects to dashboard before login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have auth routes and unauthenticated routes which would just be the login page. When a user auth token expires in localstorage, it removes the item from localstorage, shows an error message briefly on the page, then redirects. How can I make it redirect to the login page before it shows any error message. I have login in unauthenticated route:

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      getItem(TOKEN) ? (
        <Layout>
          <Component {...props} />
        </layout>
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: '/login',
          }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
);

const UnauthenticatedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      !getItem(TOKEN) ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: '/',
          }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
);
```

And this is a sample page on my app:

```
  const { id } = useContext(UserContext);
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(QUERY, {
    variables: { id },
  });

if (loading) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  if (error)) {
    console.log(error);

    return <Alert message="Error" />;
  }

  return (
    <PersonPage
      props={}
    />
  );
```

Im not really sure why it doesnt go straight to the login page.
This is where i check if the refresh token is expired using graphql:

```
case 'INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR':
              if (err) {
                removeItem(AUTH_TOKEN);
                // history.push('/login');
                // return <Redirect to="/login" />;
              }
```

Ive tried both and no luck.

Edit.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import MasterLayout from '';
import { AUTH_TOKEN } from 'constants';

// import { getItem } from 'utils/localStorage';

import useLocalStorage from 'react-use-localstorage';

const ProtectedRouteWithLayout = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const [authToken] = useLocalStorage(AUTH_TOKEN);

  console.log(authToken);

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        authToken ? (
          <MasterLayout>
            {console.log(authToken)}
            <Component {...props} />
          </MasterLayout>
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/login',
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

export default ProtectedRouteWithLayout;
```

Comment: Could you show the `Alert` component and be a bit more specific about when the redirect happens? Does the alert require user interaction before redirect can happen or is it just a flash of content before redirecting automatically?

Comment: The alert component is from antdesign and it is just a flash of alert before redirecting automatically. The redirect should happen when I remove the auth token from local storage. History.push works but it still shows a quick error flash on the page before redirecting to the login screen @lawrence-witt

Comment: to show the message after redirection, you can add an query parameter, like `/login?error_message=token_expired`, if you are explicitly redirecting using react router or window location. Otherwise, you can add a localstorage item `error_message=token_expired` so your login component can display it and delete it them

Comment: The issue is that it shows an error message and doesnt redirect right away @Jerryc

Comment: looks like your `UnauthenticatedRoute` and `ProtectedRoute` is not re-rendering. after you remove the item from localstorage, these components are not getting notified.  you can use something like `react-use-localstorage`, to link up the localstorage item to an react state, so that the component will re-render

Comment: @Jerryc I tried implementing the react-use-localstorage library and it still doesnt re-render in the protected auth when the access token changes

Comment: can you show your code or even better share a codesandbox link

Comment: @Jerryc I added the code to the edit. I cant make a sandbox the file is too large

Comment: authToken doesnt log when changes are made to the localstorage @Jerryc

Comment: looks good to me, is  the constant AUTH_TOKEN not correct or some kinds of logic prevent the component from re-rendering?

Comment: @Jerryc the AUTH_TOKEN is correct. When I go to different tab components in the navbar, the page loads for a split second, then redirects once it realizes there is no auth token. I need it to go straight back to the login page dont even show the component

Comment: yes, the main cause is the route component not re-rendering. I cannot see any issue in the code your showed. it can be a bug from react-use-localstorage, you can try out another lib or code. good luck